# Google cloud or Docker not recognizing folder

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gcloud, google-cloud-build, docker-build

I have a project with the following strucure :

```
vineetkalghatgi@vinux:~/personal-projects/bertQA_server$ ls
bert-server-env  cloudbuild.yaml  Dockerfile  main.py  mymodel  Procfile  __pycache__  README.md  requirements.txt  target
```

My .dockerignore:

```
Dockerfile
README.md
*.pyc
*.pyo
*.pyd
__pycache__
.pytest_cache
bert-server-env
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
ADD mymodel .
COPY . .

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get autoremove -y \
    && apt-get clean

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
# Timeout is set to 0 to disable the timeouts of the workers to allow Cloud Run to handle instance scaling.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

I previously just had `COPY . .` without the `ADD` and noticed that the 'mymodel' folder was not getting copied.
If i run `gcloud build submit . --tag <my-gcr.io-container` I get the following error:

```
Step 5/9 : ADD mymodel .
ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat mymodel: file does not exist
```

And I am able to build the image locally with `docker build` with no issues.

Comment: Seems like the `mymodel` folder never reach to the context model. 
Do you have a hidden .gcloudignore file?

To verify you can try adding a step to list the files in the build work folder

{name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud, entrypoint: /bin/bash, args: ['-c', 'ls -la']}

Answer (score 2):

With `gcloud build submit`, if you have a `Dockerfile` in the working directory, you don't need a `cloudbuild.yaml`. Because you have a `cloudbuild.yaml`, I suspect that it is taking priority.

Q1: What is the content of `cloudbuild.yaml`?

Cloud SDK uses a `.gcloudignore` file to ignore files that are e.g. uploaded to Cloud Build.

Q2: Do you have a `.gcloudignore` file or `.gitignore` file?

It'd be useful to `ls -1a` (where 1==one) or l=lowercase L will show hidden files too.